# If I use a DOS put command to ftp a file, will it overwrite an existing file, append to it, or cause an error?

Tags: ftp, dos

If I use a DOS put command to ftp a file, will it overwrite an existing file, append to it, or cause an error?

Comment: What do you mean by "DOS put command"?

Comment: I can say with 98.5% confidence that you're not using DOS. Terminal window != DOS.

Answer (score 7):

put and get will both overwrite

Answer (score 5):

Do you mean if you use a 'put' command in the command line ftp app?  It will overwrite.

Comment: Guess it depends on which side you want to overwrite.